# How to find unnamed component that throws warning

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I have the following warnings in console:

[image: screenshot of console output]

I can see it is a recompose component but have no idea where to find it. Here is too many components in the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use React DevTools there is usually a path shown on bottom right corner. It might help. If you find a right js line.

Comment: I didn't get the useful line number. The line number of warning is in warning.js (fbjs).

Comment: @GuoYunhe There are many lines. The line with `index.tsx` likely refers to your own piece of code.

Comment: @estus Thanks! You are right. I should use componentDidMount other than componentWillMount.